# XMLHttpRequest в цикле

Tags: ajax, javascript

Нужно отправить неизвестное количество запросов в асинхронном режиме. Зациклить на саму функцию нет возможности. С синхронным всё просто, что делать с асинхронным?

**Дополнено из комментария.**

Более подробно:

```
function ololo() {
    for (var i = 0; i < xz; i++) {
        var url = "http://myserver.com/my.php?req=i";
        //тут как-то передать асинхронно запрос по этому урл
        //получаем ответ от сервера и на основании его ответа
        if (respon == "da") {
            var url = "http://myserver.com/my.php?req=nyaga";
        } else {
            var url = "http://myserver.com/my.php?req=nynetyj";
        }
        //опять асинхронный запрос
    }
}
```

Comment: Перенесено в вопрос.

Comment: Так LOL так бы и написали что нужна асинхронная цепочка.

Comment: Я откровенно говоря не понимаю в чем смысл.

Или следующий запрос уже должен отправляться по URL'у сформированому на ответе сервера?

И все-же - что значит зациклить на функцию нет возможности?..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не уверен что понял слова "зациклить на саму функцию нет возможности", но попытаюсь ответить.

Непосредственно для решения проблемы( без академического примера и разбора как оно работает и т.д. ). Используем jquery ( на самом деле от jquery тут берется только ajax API, deferred - это отдельная библиотека, которую, при необходимости, можно скачать и использовать примерно так-же, ну да не суть ). 
Для инфы: внедрилось в jquery это относительно недавно.

```
$.when($.get("url1"), $.get("url2")).done(function(res1,  res1){/* res1, res2 ответы сервера */});
```

Соответственно - вы можете сделать столько XHR запросов сколько пожелаете.

Поскольку количество запросов неизвестно, то прийдеться как-то извращаться, но тут уже разберетесь сами. (не все-же за вас делать =))

---

Ну и теперь более "широкий" ответ, скорее общего характера о псевдо-паралельном выполнении и о том, как примерно это реализовывается. Я мог бы написать намного больше, но это превратиться в главу книги, а не в ответ на вопрос.

Для начала реализуем возможность асинхронного цикла. Код я писал как под Node.js так и под браузерный JS (это к тому что-бы было понятно откуда берется название 'nextTick', process и т.д.)

```
// приведем к единому виду глобальную переменную
// в браузерном JS это window, в ноде - global
var Global = typeof global === 'undefined' ? window : global;

var nextTick = (function() {
    var nextTickFunction;
    if(typeof process !== 'undefined') {
        // если это нода
        nextTickFunction = process.nextTick;
    }
    else {
        // в противном случае - пишем свою реализацию
        // благо это элементарно
        nextTickFunction = function(func) {
            setTimeout(func, 1);
        }
    }
    return nextTickFunction;
}());

// реализация асинхронного цикла for
Array.prototype.iterate = function( cb, finish ) {
    finish = finish !== undefined&&finish.constructor===Function?finish:function(){};
    var thisLength = this.length;
    var array = this;
    function step( i ) {
        cb( array[ i ], i );
        if( ++i  <= thisLength - 1 ) {
            nextTick( function() {
                step( i );
            });
        }
        else {
            nextTick( function() {
                finish();   
            });
        }
    };
    thisLength ? step(0) : finish();
};
```

Имея эту базу мы можем написать неблокирующую имитацию паралельного выполнения. Функция еще нормально не тестировалась (вроде работает =)) и, по сути, не дописана (в большей степени просто плохо написана), но идея должна быть ясна.

```
function parallel() {
var first = arguments[0];
if( first ) {
    var results, methods = [], callback = function(){};
    if(first.constructor === Function) {
        results = [];
        if(arguments !== undefined)
        for( var i=0, l=arguments.length; i<l; ++i ) {
            var value = arguments[i];
            if(i !== l-1) {
                methods.push( value );  
            }
            else {
                callback = value;
            }
        }   
        methods.iterate(function(func, i) {
            nextTick(function() {
                func.call({
                    end : function( res ) {
                        methods[i].__done__ = true;
                        results[i] = res;
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    }
    else {
        var keys = [];
        results  = {};
        callback = arguments[1] !== undefined ? arguments[1] : function(){}; 
        var methodsData = first;
        for( var i in first ) {
            keys.push( i );
            methods.push( first[i] );
        }
        methods.iterate(function(func, i) {
            nextTick(function() {
                func.call({
                    end : function( res ) {
                        methods[i].__done__ = true;
                        results[keys[i]] = res;
                    }
                })
            })
        });
    }
}

function isDone() {
    var done = true;
    for(var i=0, l=methods.length; i<l; ++i) {
        if(!methods[i].__done__) {
            done = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    return done;
}

function finish() {
    nextTick(function() {
        var done = isDone();
        if(!done) {
            finish();
        }
        else {
            if( results.constructor === Array ) {
                callback.apply( Global, results );
            }
            else {
                callback( results );
            }
        }
    });
}

nextTick(finish);
```

};

Теперь немного о том как это работает - функция принимает неопределенное количество параметров, все параметры должны быть функциями, подразумевается что последняя функция это обработчик результата когда все функции отработали, соответственно все аргументы до него - функции к выполнению. Так-же функция может принимать 2 параметра, где первый параметр это хэш функций для выполнения, а второй - обработчик. Разница в том, что если использовать первый вариант, в обработчик результаты будут переданы путем вызова `apply` и передачей массива результатов ( в той очередности в которой были переданы функции ), в случае передачи объекта - обработчику передается 1 параметр - хэш результатов, где ключ переданного хэша и будет результатом выполнения той или иной функции.

Вообщем полностью обьяснять не буду (к сожалению очень многа букафф), лучше приведу примеры использования.

```
parallel({
    'test1' : function(){
        this.end(1);
    },
    'test2' : function(){
        this.end(2);
    }
}, function( results ) {
    console.log( results ); // -> { test1: 1, test2 : 2 }
})
```

Как мы видим из примера - сигнализировать о завершении своей работы функция должна путем вызова метода end. Метод end нам доступен т.к. функции вызываются не на прямую а с помощью прототипного метода Function call, которому, в качестве параметра, передается объект с уникальной реализацией метода end (уникальной т.к. формируется динамически для каждой конкретной функции). Ну и еще пример:

```
parallel(
    function(){
        this.end(1);
    },
    function(){
        this.end(2);
    },
    function( param1, param2 ) {
        console.log( param1 ); // -> 1
        console.log( param2 ); // -> 2
})
```

Собственно функции, как и в примере выше, должны вызвать метод end дабы сигнализировать о своем завершении.

Теперь о неудобстве в случае с неопределенным количеством xhr запросов - мы не сможем вызвать метод end в обработчике onreadystatechange т.к. у нас будет изменен контекст this, соответственно мы должны будм сделать что-то типа:

```
function() {
    var _end = this.end;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    // your code here
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(this.radyState === 4) {
             _end( this.responseText );
        }
    }
}
```

Ну вот собственно и все. Вы можете легко и непринужденно использовать данный подход для любого количества XHR запросов. Более того, использую такой подход вы можете, например, пройтись по массиву в 10кк элементов (не спрашивайте как его инициалезировать и зачем, просто пример =).) не блокирую поток выполнения. Так-же большой профит может быть, например, при разработке толстых клиентов или, например html5 игр, ну и естественно - это удобно и выгодно в контексте Node.js. Еще, например, можно - выполнять какую-то длительный цикл или цепочку функций "в фоновом режиме" и т.д. Важно понимать что такой подход нужно применять только тогда, когда нужно =)

PS: Данная инфа должна быть очень полезной для изучающих Node.js

PPS: Если кому-то интересно - напишу комментарии к коду.

Comment: Ниче так накатал. +