# Как в переменную загрузить данные из файла?

Tags: javascript, html, mustache

Здравствуйте!

Есть сторонняя библиотека работы с шаблонами  Mustache. При заполнении шаблона, я использую два входных параметра, это файл шаблона и файл содержащий JSON строку, содержимое которой подставляется в шаблон.

Первый вопрос: как загрузить эти файлы непосредственно в переменные, для передачи их в  Mustache функцию, например:

```
html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
```

Второй вопрос: Может можно сразу указывать в качестве входных параметров Mustache функции, пути к файлам:

```
html = Mustache.to_html(File_path_to_template, File_path_to_json);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function getData( url, ready ) {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open( 'GET', url, true );
  xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if( this.readyState === 4 && this.status !== 404 ) {
    ready( this.responseText );
   }
  }
  xhr.send();
}

getData( 'pathToTemplate', function( templateData ) {
  getData( 'pathToJSON', function( jsonData ) {
    console.log( templateData );
    console.log( jsonData );
  })
})
```

Асинхронный вариант, по хорошему нужно делать примерно так, а в вашем случае вообще лучше делать запросы "паралельно", [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/87809/xmlhttprequest-%D0%B2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1&focusedAnswerId=87817#87817) я кое-что писал об этом.

Answer (score 1):

```
var json;
$.get('/data.json', function (data) {
 json = data;
});
alert(json.test);
```

На чистом JS сами пишите.

Comment: а на чем это?

Comment: Это с использованием библиотеки jQuery

Comment: Да ну?

    var omg;
    $.get('url', function( data ) { omg = data; })
    console.log( omg ); // -> undefined

Вы бы хоть проверили чтоле.. Это не говоря о том, что это очевидно

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, вам подойдет такая немудреная функция:

```
loadURL = function(url) {
    var oRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oRequest.open('GET', url, false);
    oRequest.setRequestHeader("User-Agent", navigator.userAgent);
    oRequest.send(null);

    return oRequest.responseText;
};
```

Я ее успешно использую в своем приложении для загрузки данных из текстовых фалов.

Answer (score 0):

Я реши проблему так:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html, json, template;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){                
            jQuery.get('File.htm', {},function(temp){
                template = temp;
            }, 'text')   
        jQuery.getJSON('data.json', {} ,function(jso){
                json = jso;
        })              
            jQuery('#click').click(function(){
        html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
        document.write(html);                                
            })
    });     
</script>
```

Comment: криво и раз уже юзаете jquery - делайте сразу несколько запросов

Comment: а как можно сделать, что бы обходиться без 
      jQuery('#click').click(function(){
т.е., что бы 
        html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
        document.write(html);

выполнялись в теле
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){
а то приходится, что бы полностью сформировалась страница еще нажимать на "кнопку" на странице

Comment: .

    (function(){
       // тут ваш код 
    }())

Comment: перепробывал разные комбинации не хочет...
вот например так:
<script type="text/javascript">
    var html, json, template;
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){                
            jQuery.get('File.htm', {},function(temp){
                template = temp;
            }, 'text')   
        jQuery.getJSON('data.json', {} ,function(jso){
                json = jso;
        })            
        html = Mustache.to_html(template, json);
        document.write(html);            
    });     
</script>

Comment: Я же написал в комментариях к ответу @exec - это не работает, напишите код так, как я вам предложил, либо как предложил @Антон Мухин.